# Sending html table data to a flask method and retrieve information from the database

Tags: python, html, forms, sqlite, flask

I've been working on a mini project in Flask using sqlite3 for DB. The project is about how to secure medical records of patients. I have two views, one is for the admin to insert new patients and view their details and another one is for patients to view their records.
My problem is that, when the admin inserts a new patient, that particular patient's name and ID will get added to the dynamic html table and also from the list of patients in the that table, he can click on a particular patient to view his/her records. But i am not able to map the viewing part of the patients records.
Im getting a run time error which says **TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement**
Here are the templates:

dyanmic table with patients name and ID:

```
 {% block content %}
    <form method="post" action="{{ url_for('custom') }}">
<table>
  <thead>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
  </thead>

    {% for row in rows %}
    <tr>


                <td name="userid1"><a href="{{ url_for('custom') }}" >{{ row.Userid }}</a></td>
                <input type="hidden" id="id" name="userid1"  value=" {{ row.Userid }}"/>
                <td name="names1"><a href="{{ url_for('custom') }}" > {{row.Name}}</a></td>
                <input type="hidden" id='na' name="names1" value="{{row.Name}}" />
                <td> {{ row["Age"]}}</td>
            </tr>
         {% endfor %}
</table>
    <br><br>
    </form>``
{% endblock %}
```

patient records page (viewing):

```
</div>
</div>
<div class="details" style="height:550px;" >
    <img src="static/images/bg2.png" style="width:250px;height:300px;margin-top:3%;">
    <div class="contentin">
      <p class="tit1"><b>{{ infos[1] }}</b></p>
      <b><p class="tit2">Age:&nbsp;&nbsp;<font style="color:black;">{{ infos[2] }}</font></p>
      <p class="tit2">Sex:&nbsp;&nbsp;<font style="color:black;">{{ infos[3] }}</font></p>
      <p class="tit2">Height:&nbsp;&nbsp;<font style="color:black;">{{ infos[4] }}</font></p>
      <p class="tit2">Weight:&nbsp;&nbsp;<font style="color:black;">{{ infos[5] }}</font></p>
       <p class="tit2">Sugar Level:&nbsp;&nbsp;<font style="color:black;">{{ infos[6] }}</font></p>
       <p class="tit2">BP Level:&nbsp;&nbsp;<font style="color:black;">{{ infos[7] }}</font></p>
       </b>
      <button class="btn" style="width:350px;"><font style="color:white;"><b>Download All Reports&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-download"></i></button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<button class="btn" style="width:300px;">Share&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-share-alt"></i></b></font></button></center>

    </div>
</div>
```

my Flask .py file:

```
@app.route('/patientinfo')
def patientinfo():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('patients.db')
    conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row

    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("select Userid,Name,Age from details")

    rows = c.fetchall()
    return render_template("patientinfo.html", rows=rows)


@app.route('/hospital', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def custom():
    User_ID = request.form.get("userid1")
    Name = request.form.get("names1")
    conn = sqlite3.connect('patients.db')
    cul = conn.cursor()
    cul.execute('SELECT Userid, Name, Age, Sex, Height, Weight, Sugar, BP from details')
    pt = cul.fetchall()
    for pat in pt:
        if pat[0] == User_ID:
            if pat[1] == Name:
                return render_template("hospital.html", infos=pat)
```

Answer (score -1):

When user clicks on the the link in the `<td>`, a GET request is sent. This `request.form.get("userid1")` will return `None` (as will `request.form.get("names1")`). This `if pat[0] == User_ID:` will never be true. Program falls through and does not return a valid response. That's why it's happening. Since this is patient data (and from a US perspective) you likely shouldn't send the id/name in a query string ie GET request). Maybe javascript has to be introduced. Take some time and contemplate the options viz. this new information.